# Proving a matrix is invertible given equation (without identity matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I'm given a square matrix ${A}$ (3×3) and the following equation ${A}^3-2017{A}^2 + {A} = {0}$ and I have to find if ${A}$ is invertible in some cases, no cases, or all cases.

I can find ${A}=0$ as an answer for the non invertible case, but I can't seem to solve the equation. In most other examples I've found, there was an identity matrix, which made it easy to find the invertible of ${A}$ like this: ${A}*invertible=I$ but this is not the case here.

I've tried doing this: $A*(A*(-A+2017*I))=A*I$, but I don't think I can divide both parts by ${A}$ because I haven't proven that ${A}$ is invertible.

Comment: Well, you've already shown that 'all cases' is not the answer, since the matrix $A=0$ is a solution but is not invertible. It remains to determine whether or not there is some invertible matrix $A$ that satisfies the equation.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's the part where I'm stuck.

Comment: If you find it easier to deal with an equation with $I$, consider the following: suppose there is some invertible matrix $A$ that satisfies the equation and multiply both sides of the equation by $A^{-1}$. Do you think you can take it from here?

Comment: Is the matrix $3\times 3$?

Comment: @Bernard yes it is

Comment: @Fimpellizieri but by multiplying both sides with $A^{-1}$, I'm using the invertible matrix of a matrix of which I'm trying to proof it's invertible.

Comment: @RobinDeBaets You will get a new equation. If you show that this new equation has only non-invertible solutions, then you will know that the original equation has no invertible solutions. If you show that the new equation has an invertible solution, you will also have found an invertible solution for the original equation.

Comment: @RobinDeBaets you can instead of multiplying by $A^{-1}$ factor out $A$ and try to draw conclusions of the nullspaces of the matrix factors.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking $A$ to be a matrix of the form $\lambda I$, and use the equation to determine what $\lambda$ must be.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. What's your point? Can you elaborate?

Comment: So this shows that a nonzero scalar multiple of $I$ can't be $A$.  How does this eliminate any other matrices (i.e., exercise the other six degrees of freedom off the diagonal)?

Comment: I'm not trying to eliminate anything, I'm trying to argue that it is possible for $A$ to be invertible. Taking $\lambda$ to be either of the two nonzero roots of the polynomial $p(x)=x^3-2017x^2+x$ will work.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the $3X3$ matrix is:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\\g&h&i\end{bmatrix}
$$

The characteristic polynomial of A is given by: $$\mu_A[x]=det(A - \lambda I_{3})$$ If we compute this we will find that the constant factor of the characteristic polynomial of A is:
$$
\mu_A[x]= ...\lambda^3 + ... \lambda^2 + ... \lambda + (-aei +afh + bdi - bfg-cdh+ceg)
$$
As we have given that the constant factor equals to $0$ and we know that $$det(A) = det(A^t) = (-aei +afh + bdi - bfg-cdh+ceg)$$
Which leads us to the fact that 
$$det(A) = 0$$
Which means that A is never invertible.

Comment: Which is just the same as already given: the constant factor of a characteristic polynomial of a matrix A is the determinant of A.

Comment: This way of solving is thus only correct if the given polynomial is actually the characteristic polynomial. My bad.

Comment: No problem @Manu, we all make mistakes